# Power BI dynamic csv file path change

Tags: powerbi

I need to change the csv file path dynamically everyday on refresh. Like it would be path/filename_01_Dec_20.csv tomorrow it should be path/filename_02_Dec_20.csv, this way it will change daily. Please let me know if this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the query for one of the CSV tables but modify the code where the filepath is specified from e.g.

```
.../filename_01_Dec_20.csv"...
```

To

```
.../filename_" & Date.ToText(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), "dd_MMM_yy") & ".csv"...
```

This just puts the current date `DateTime.LocalNow()` in the format you're looking for using the `Date.ToText` formatting function.

Comment: It is working when I am doing in power bi desktop. I am getting an error when using in power bi report server.. unable to fetch the file through date wise